# Simplifying A List

Tags: python

I need to simplify this list of numbers but have it so that it also includes a certain letter, how can I simplify my list?

Right now I've already made the list however I need some code which randomly chooses a certain number out of this list.

```py
carddeck = ['r01', 'r02', 'r03', 'r04', 'r05', 'r06', 'r07', 'r08', 'r09', 'r10', 'b01', 'b02', 'b03', 'b04', 'b05', 'b06', 'b07', 'b08', 'b09', 'b10', 'y01', 'y02', 'y03', 'y04', 'y05', 'y06', 'y07', 'y08','y09', 'y10']
colours =  ['red', 'black', 'yellow']
validOptionsR = ['r01', 'r02', 'r03', 'r04', 'r05', 'r06', 'r07', 'r08', 'r09', 'r10']
validOptionsB = ['b01', 'b02', 'b03', 'b04', 'b05', 'b06', 'b07', 'b08', 'b09', 'b10']
validOptionsY = ['y01', 'y02', 'y03', 'y04', 'y05', 'y06', 'y07', 'y08','y09', 'y10']
```

I'd like a code which doesn't use the full list but instead picks a random number from 01 to 10 and put it alongside the chosen colour, for example, a black card would be b09. here is the rest of my code:

```py
rndClr = random.choice(colours)

if rndClr.find('black'):
        rndClr = 'black'
        print('black')

elif rndClr.find('yellow'):
        rndClr = 'yellow'
        print('yellow')

elif rndClr.find('red'):
        rndClr = 'red'
        print('red')

else:
    print('An Error Has Occurred While Calculating the Card Colour')

def colourPicker():
    colourWind = Tk()
    colourWind.title('Cards')
    colourWind.configure(bg = rndClr)

def playerCardPick():
    if rndClr == 'red' :
         random.shuffle(validOptionsR)
         chosencard = random.choice(validOptionsR)

    elif rndClr == 'black' :
         random.shuffle(validOptionsB)
         chosencard = random.choice(validOptionsB)

    else:
         random.shuffle(validOptionsY)
         chosencard = random.choice(validOptionsY)

    print(str(chosencard))
```

Comment: It is not clear, what you are asking.

Comment: Asking for a code that randomly chooses a number from 01 to 10 without having to use the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with

```py
print(rndColor[0] + str(random.randint(1, 11)))
```

It takes the first letter of your color and prepends it to a random number between 1 and 10.

Also, the if-else-if ladder can be condensed to

```py
if rndColor not in color:
    print("Error message here")
    exit()
```

But I don't think that rndColor will take any value not in the list. Not sure though